# Multiple HDMI inputs saving on computer

Tags: video, hardware

I am recording something with multiple cameras at the same time. I need a set up that will allow me to take the output from the camera and through HDMI or some other output, connect it to the computer and save it. I was thinking of a product that maybe has 10 different HDMI ports and a USB output port that allows me to access, the content of the HDMI cables.

Do you guys think its possible if so how can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to record each camera SEPARATELY (called "ISO") or whether you are doing some kind of real-time COMBINING ("video mixing").  If you are recording separately, then you will need a very high-performing computer to record multiple video streams.  If you are recording a live-mix then most any modern computer will work. And there are probably non-computer solutions that are easier and less expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to record all 3 feeds at the same time and not mix you could get 3 decklink mini recorder cards: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/964122-REG/blackmagic_design_decklink_mini_recorder.html I don't know how well it would work recording 3 feeds at once, youd definitely need large ssds.

Alternatively you could record in the camera or use some atomos ninja recorders: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/759460-REG/ATOMOS_ATOMNJA003_Ninja_Video_Hard_Disk.html I love these and use them all the time.

Comment: Even with SSDs, you'll probably need a properly tuned RAID/storage subsystem to handle the IOPS on a single machine. There will probably be quite a bit of processor overhead if you want to compress the recordings, though that will save some on the storage requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a Video Production Switcher. This is what broadcasters use to switch between video sources (including multiple cameras, pre-recorded clip playback, computer video, etc.)

There are some software solutions and some hardware solutions. While the software solutions seem less expensive (some even free), they make heavy requirements on the computer, and require in many cases expensive input interface cards with multiple video inputs.

There are hardware solutions which are more traditional for video production. Some of them have H.264 USB output to feed directly into your computer for recording or live streaming.  For example I have several video switchers from BlackMagic Design. Their "TV Studio" low-end model has direct H.264 output via USB.

Comment: ok what software can I use with the USB recorders, to manage the live stream layout etc Let's say Cam 1 display as main image, and cam 2 on a window. Similar to this http://signlangtv.org/www/img-tv/ant1-n-ep.jpg

Comment: Special effects like combining two cameras plus the "frame" is what the video production switcher does.  That is done BEFORE you get to USB recorders.

Comment: Ok the thing is, I have a really powerful computer I can use. I want to just input everything there and use the software to manage it from inside the computer and then stream it.

Comment: Then you need to buy enough HDMI input channels for your computer so that you can use a software-implemented video production switcher application.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_vision_mixer

Answer (score 0):

I made a extended answer about this similar question, where I recommend Blackmagic hardware, any computer and Open Broadcaster Software.

[The answer can be found here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19174/multi-source-picture-in-picture-live-stream/19625#19625).